# about islamic education animation

Tags: drawing, cartoon

assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh

so i want to ask something, i know that drawing inanimate objects are strictly forbidden, but i also see some controversy between the scholar about this issue, wether it's allowed with some term and condition. now what I'm curious about is, what about animation with inanimate objects, that teaches about Islam, like cartoon or just comic characters, for example there's one famous islamic cartoon called omar and hana, i haven't watched it but from the looks of it, it's seems like cartoon that teaches kids, or adult that might just come to Islam about our religion. what's the ruling about those things? thank you

wassalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with watching anime if it does not cause sin. If the animation does not cause sexual arousal or is not accompanied by a pleasant song, then there is no problem.
[Read more](https://vaislamah.com/pgquestionanswer/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%D9%85%DB%8C%D8%B4%D9%86-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%9F/)